# Rails Twitter Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Rails 3.2.12, Ruby 2.0, with Twitter Bootstrap Gem, and I am trying to implement Carousel div to my App, but it is looking horrible at the moment, only two big buttons are shown, one at left part of the screen, other on the right.

Is there are any successful examples of how to correctly implement Carousel? Should I add additional div's to my code?

I got no custom css in my bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less file except this one:

> body { padding-top: 60px;}

```
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="<%= root_path %>">ProjectX</a>
      <div class="container nav-collapse">
       <ul class="nav">
         <% if current_user %>
            <li class="nav-header"><%= current_user.email %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path %></li>
          </ul>
        <% else %>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><%= link_to "Log In", login_path  %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", signup_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Forum", "/path3"  %></li>
        </ul>
        <% end %>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
   Carousel items
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item"></div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span9">
        <%= bootstrap_flash %>
        <%= yield %>
      </div>
      <div class="span3">
        <div class="well sidebar-nav">
          <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
            <li><%= link_to "News", "/path1"  %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Recent", "/path2"  %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Hot Topics", "/path3"  %></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.well -->
      </div><!--/span-->
    </div><!--/row-->

  <footer>
    <p>&copy;Iron Man</p>
  </footer>

</div> <!-- /container -->

<!-- Javascripts
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Focus on `<div class="carousel-inner"`. Within it, you'll notice three nested divs with `class="item"`. Each of these nested classes need to reference an image for your carousel to work.

You currently have nothing between these div tags:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">  
  <div class="active item"></div> 
  <div class="item">...</div>  
  <div class="item">...</div> 
</div>
```

Here's an example of what you want to do:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">  
  <div class="active item"><img src='https://dev.twitter.com/sites/default/files/images_platform_object/arctic-blue-bird.jpg?1334604325'></div> 
  <div class="item"><img src='https://dev.twitter.com/sites/default/files/images_platform_object/missouri_meadow_lark.jpg?1334604578'></div>  
  <div class="item"><img src='https://dev.twitter.com/sites/default/files/images_platform_object/yellow_flycatcher.jpg?1334605975'></div> 
</div>
```

The images that I have included are from Twitter, and they specify an absolute path. You can, in other words, cut and paste this code into the rest of the carousel template to view the images.